# unknown notation |Z|

Tags: algorithm, notation

I was reading a PDF about SHA-3 but on [this page](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf#page=27&zoom=auto,-205,752) I was confronted to a notation that I don't undertand.

It's **|Z|** on step 9. I thought that was the length of the String **Z** but but in this case it would be written **len(Z)**. Different notations were explained on [this page](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf#page=13&zoom=auto,-265,404) but **|Z|** does not figure.

The line in question :

> If d≤|Z|, then return Truncd(Z); else continue.
>
> with d a nonnegative integer and Z a string

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure it's still meant be be then length of the string.

Comment: If it would be the case, considering the whole SHA-3 algorithm, the condition would be always verifyed. So I don't think that it mean the length.

Comment: Ha no. My bad, I forgot the Shake128 and the shake256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here https://keccak.team/files/SpongeDuplex.pdf
On page 3, section Sequrity requirements, given such explanation:
"|x| is the bitlength of string x"
Think it should be this value.

Comment: Ok thanks, it must be that. Still strange that they defined **len(X)** as the length of X in bits, and then use another notation for the same thing.